# Oracle Application Server Integration With APEX

Tags: oracle-11g, reporting, oracle-apex

This might not be directly related to DBA, if so kindly advise.

I need to integrated some reports created via Oracle Reports Builder with APEX. Reports are in RDF format.

Which version of Oracle Application server should be installed and are there any pre-req for Windows server with oracle 11g running.